# File not found error occur when read property file in java

Tags: java, properties, classpath

i create the property file under package of `resources/common/configure/`

then i create the code

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    try {
           //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("resources/common/configure/commonData.properties"));

           //get the property value and print it out
            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("id"));


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i got the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

please let me know how can i get this property file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with

```
prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/common/configure/commonData.properties"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The program tries to find the "commonData.properties" at a path specified relative to where you are running it. Providing a correct relative path or full path of configuration file might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute file paths. Print the full path and you'll be able to spot your problem.

Alternatively, use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.